# Downloading data layer from website map based on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, coordinates

This website https://www.oplaadpalen.nl has a map with markers of charging stations.

Is there a way to get the coordinates of each marker from the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can inspect the network traffic using your browser developer tool and find that you get a 1.5 Mb file with the JSON data of all charging stations.

However, it would be best to follow the developer link on the page you posted, which leads [here](https://oplaadpalen.nl/api/chargingpoints) where you can get a key for their API and then legally get the data. As a bonus this page will explain the structure of the returned Json.

Answer (score 4):

I'd originally answered "no", but JGH has pointed out that the data *can* be found using developer tools in your browser, and you should refer to his answer for that.

A bit of searching also reveals that the data is available from that site as a KML, and has also been converted to a shapefile, available via VU Amsterdam's [Geoplaza](http://geoplaza.vu.nl/data/dataset/charging-stations-oplaadpalen/resource/b64cccda-aac2-49ea-a41f-f410e00b4534).

Please note that this is the kind of searching expected to be put in by the asker prior to a question being posed here.

Comment: it IS just sitting there...

Comment: Oh! You're right, it is. My use of the developer tools is not up to par, I suppose.